# brew tap caskroom/cask complains about git

Tags: git, macos, homebrew, osxfuse

When I run `brew tap caskroom/cask` I get conflicting error messages.

```
Warning: git 2.15.1 is already installed
Error: Git must be installed and in your PATH!
```

Previously I ran `brew link --overwrite  git` when brew asked me too.

Git seems to be installed fine and it is indeed in my path:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.15.1
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git
$ echo $PATH
/Users/selah/anaconda3/bin:/Applications/instantclient_12_1:/Users/selah/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

My ultimate goal is to run `brew info osxfuse` successfully.  Currently I get the following errors:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "osxfuse" 
It was migrated from homebrew/core to caskroom/cask.
You can access it again by running:
  brew tap caskroom/cask
```

Can anyone help me to make it past this `brew tap` error so that brew can view info for osxfuse?

Answer (score 2):

I installed developer tools and this corrected my issue:

```
xcode-select --install
```